# BASH: auto-completing $keyword for printf "%s"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I must find a non-trivial approach for a trivial printf "%s".
In my case all keywords are a physical files in different locations.
I would like to be able using a tab button to complete locations/files just as with CLI, and display all the files if they start with the same letters.
Is it possible to add the index of the system to a bash script?
Eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "%s" "The file is: "
read keyword
```

~~~~~~~~~

```
./script.sh
The file is: /home/user/file
(Hit tab)
file.txt file2 file5
/home/user/file.
(Hit tab)
/home/user/file.txt
```

The files can be in different locations. Only 1 parameter will be provided at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` isn't relevant here; it's `read` for which you want completion. In `bash`, enable `Readline` support with the `-e` option.

```
read -e keyword
```

You can do away with the `printf` command altogether, by the way, by using the `-p` option to print the prompt:

```
read -p "The file is: " -e keyword
```